# replace rows in a zero matrix with rows from anothrer matrix - rowlengths are already the same

Tags: matlab, replace

`matrix_zeros` is a 15 rows by 10 columns of zeros - it is 15 rows long because the zeros were created to to cater to number of rows in `matrix_smaller`

`matrix_smaller` is a 15 rows by 3 columns matrix of various values

I want to populate `matrix_zeros` - say columns 4,6,8 with the values in `matrix_smaller` columns 1,2,3  i.e. column 1 from `matrix_smaller` goes into column 4 in `matrix_zeros`, column 2 from `matrix_smaller` into column 6 from `matrixzeros` etc...

All other columns remain 0

Many thanks

Comment: 10x 15 and 3x15 mean 10 rows and 15 columns and 3 rows and 15 columns... do you mean it the other way around?

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do is this:

```
matrixzeros(:,[ 4 6 8 ]) = matrix_smaller;
```

So that selects all rows and columns 4, 6 and 8 from `matrixzeros`, giving a target 15x3 matrix, and sets them to be the contents of `matrix_smaller`.

Please be careful when describing the size of your matricies; according to the text you mean 15 rows, but matrices are described as *row* x *column*.  Therefore you mean 15x10 and 15x3.